# передача аргументов функции python

Tags: python, django, token

вот какая ситуация.
Есть функция

```
def get_token(callback):
  "работа с данными"
return token
```

и следующая функция

```
def view_data(request):
    "код"
return render(request, 'мой_хтм_шаблон', {"data": data}
```

Как передать переменную token из функции get_token в функцию view_data?
При стандартной передачи аргументов появляется ошибка

```
view_data() missing 1 required positional argument: 'token'
```

переменную передаю так:

```
def get_token(callback):
      "работа с данными"
    view_data(token)
    return token

def view_data(request, token):
"код"
```

Comment: view_data хочет получить кроме токена еще и request

Comment: ``def view_data(request)`` или ``def view_data(request, token)``?

Comment: def view_data(request, token)
при такой конструкции возникает эта ошибка

Comment: Вы явно что-то не договариваете. Что такое `callback` у `get_token`?

Comment: callback  - это переменная с ответом от стороннего сервера, которая содержит json файл, из которого я получаю токен